# wp remote get and advanced custom fields returning hundreds of duplicates

Tags: php, wordpress

I found a tutorial explaining how to use `wp_remote_get()` and post results to WP custom post types using Advanced Custom Fields Plugin.

My problem is that when I run this from the admin dashboard as explained, I get hundreds of duplicate entries for the same product! I assume because I'm looping through pages as explained in the tutorial, but the API endpoint I'm using is not paginated, as is the one in the tutorial. I'm trying to figure out how to stop the loop from running when the newly created post already exists. Here is my code

```
<?php
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_products_from_api', 'get_products_from_api');
add_action('wp_ajax_get_products_from_api', 'get_products_from_api');

function get_products_from_api() {

    $current_page = ( ! empty($_POST['current_page']) ) ? $_POST['current_page'] : 1;
    $myproducts =[];

    $results = wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_remote_get('https://link/to/api/endpoint/'));

    $results = json_decode($results);

    if ( ! is_array( $results ) || empty ( $results ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    $myproducts[] = $results;

    foreach( $myproducts[0] as $myproduct ) {
        $myproducts_slug = $myproduct->name;

        $existing_product = get_page_by_path($myproducts_slug, 'OBJECT', 'myproduct');

        if($existing_product === null ) {

            $inserted_product = wp_insert_post([
                'post_name' => $myproducts_slug,
                'post_title' => $myproducts_slug,
                'post_type' => 'myproducts',  
                'post_status' => 'publish'
            ]);

            if (is_wp_error($inserted_product) ) {
                continue;
            }

            //ADVANCED CUSTOM FIELDS INTEGRATION
            $fillable = [ 
                'field_5dc862b619530' => 'name',
                'field_5dc862ec19531' => 'style',
                'field_5dc863269b298' => 'description',
                'field_5dc8633738fad' => 'rating',
            ];

            foreach( $fillable as $key => $name ) {
                update_field( $key, $myproducts->$name, $inserted_product );
            }
        }
    }

    $current_page = $current_page +1;
    wp_remote_post(admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=get_products_from_api'), [
        'blocking' => false,
        'sslverify' => false, 
        'body' => [
            'current_page' => $current_page
        ]
    ]);
}
```

What am I doing wrong, what am I missing? The script runs with no errors, but it just keeps going and going and making many copies of same post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out what was going on here. Due to the recursive nature of the admin-ajax call, there is no need to keep running that through pages that don't exist. While it's still necessary to run the script from wp-admin, it doesn't need to be hard coded in.

New code looks like this:

```
<?php
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_products_from_api', 'get_products_from_api');
add_action('wp_ajax_get_products_from_api', 'get_products_from_api');

function get_products_from_api() {

$current_page = ( ! empty($_POST['current_page']) ) ? $_POST['current_page'] : 1;
$myproducts =[];

$results = wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_remote_get('https://link/to/api/endpoint/'));

$results = json_decode($results);

$myproducts[] = $results;

foreach( $myproducts[0] as $myproduct ) {
    $myproducts_slug = $myproduct->name;

    $existing_product = get_page_by_path($myproducts_slug, 'OBJECT', 'myproduct');

    if($existing_product === null ) {

        $inserted_product = wp_insert_post([
            'post_name' => $myproducts_slug,
            'post_title' => $myproducts_slug,
            'post_type' => 'myproducts',  
            'post_status' => 'publish'
        ]);

        if (is_wp_error($inserted_product) ) {
            continue;
        }

        //ADVANCED CUSTOM FIELDS INTEGRATION
        $fillable = [ 
            'field_5dc862b619530' => 'name',
            'field_5dc862ec19531' => 'style',
            'field_5dc863269b298' => 'description',
            'field_5dc8633738fad' => 'rating',
        ];

        foreach( $fillable as $key => $name ) {
            update_field( $key, $myproducts->$name, $inserted_product );
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this will help someone else that runs into the same issue I did.

[Check the DIFF](https://www.diffchecker.com/rR0bnlBY)